# How to center a navigation bar with CSS?

Tags: html, css, menu, nav, centering

I am having surieuse difficulty with centering the navigation bar on [this page](https://www.algeria-cgny.org/).

I tried all and a bunch of other ways, but I still can't center it.

Comment: Do you want us to guess the code?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add `justify-content: center` to the `.primary-navigation` `class`, please leave examples or some of the code next time. Do not expect us to check the link for its code. This question and answer are similar to the ones on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-can-i-horizontally-center-an-element) stack overflow question.